# Posting to data extensions from external forms

Tags: marketing-cloud, integration, dataextensions

1. We have an external form and need to insert record from the form fields to marketing cloud data extension. Is it possible?

Can you please provide some steps?

2. If possible, then I need to validate login, ex. we have a login form , if user enter credential into that form then we need to check it if the user name and password exist or not in the data extension and based on that user will be able to login.

Can you please provide me steps?

Comment: Welcome to SFSE. Can you please share what you have done so far, to find a solution yourself? Take few minutes to [read this page](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) about asking good questions, as asking good questions will improve chances of getting an answer. Also, you ask multiple questions at once - please limit your question to one topic, and preferably share AmpScript you are trying to write.

Comment: Also, you should never keep plain text passwords within Marketing Cloud.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend #2 on this either.  Your data extensions essentially should not function the way an application data warehouse should operate.  The process to enable field-level encryption through marketing cloud would probably be too heavy of a lift based on your use case.